# Json parse array

Tags: javascript, json

Eu tenho a seguinte resposta

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "Name":"Rafael",
            "label":"teste"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "Name":"Carlos",
            "label":"teste"
        }
    ],
    "relations":[
        {
            "id":1
        },
        {
            "id":2
        }
    ]
}
```

E quero armanezar em dois arrays de objetos

```
var usersArray;
var relationsArray;
```

Tentei de varias formas e `.map(JSON.parse)` não funciona na minha página.

Comment: `var usersArray = json.users;
var relationsArray = json.relations;`

Answer (score 4):

Você pode armazenar essa resposta em uma variável e separar os dois arrays:

```js
var arrJson = {
        "users":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "Name":"Rafael",
                "label":"teste"
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "Name":"Carlos",
                "label":"teste"
            }
        ],
        "relations":[
            {
                "id":1
            },
            {
                "id":2
            }
        ]
    }

var users = arrJson.users;
var relations = arrJson.relations;

console.log(users)
console.log(relations)
```

Dessa maneira consegui, sem precisar chamar nenhum método de conversão, separar os dois Arrays

Comment: Sabe que dá pra criar um snnipet aqui no site mesmo?

Comment: Já vi em algumas respostas, mas não sei direito como faz, aí geralmente crio um Fiddle

Comment: Tem um botão **`Trecho JavaScript/HTML/CSS`** na barra superior do campo pra escrever resposta. Ou só clicar **`Ctrl + M`**

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, muito melhor kkk nunca mais vou usar o JSFiddle

Answer (score 2):

Basta atribuir às variáveis os respectivos valores do objeto:

```js
const resposta = {
    "users":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "Name":"Rafael",
            "label":"teste"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "Name":"Carlos",
            "label":"teste"
        }
    ],
    "relations":[
        {
            "id":1
        },
        {
            "id":2
        }
    ]
};

var usersArray = resposta["users"];
var relationsArray = resposta["relations"];

console.log(usersArray);
console.log(relationsArray);
```

A saída de `console.log(usersArray)` será:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "Rafael",
    "label": "teste"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "Carlos",
    "label": "teste"
  }
]
```

E de `console.log(relationsArray)` será:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```